# Upgrading jetty for geoserver

Tags: jetty, geoserver

I have GeoServer (version 2.24.1) running on a Windows Server 2022 as a servive using Jetty (version 9.4.52).

Is there any possibility to upgrade the Jetty version? If yes, what is the latest version of Jetty I can use with my version of GeoServer and what are the steps for upgrading Jetty?

Thanks in advance!

At the moment, I have no idea how to upgrade the jetty integrated in my geoserver version.

Comment: why do you need to upgrade it? I hope you are not running a production installation using  jetty? You should really be using tomcat.

Comment: Our central IT-security wants me to switch to a newer version in order to fix some security bugs. Is there a (easy) possibility to switch to a new version of Tomcat?

Comment: Just install the latest war file and point it at your existing data directory.

Comment: Jetty is run on countless millions of public websites, it's more than capable of handling anything you can throw at it.

Comment: GeoServer should be able to run on Jetty 12 with the ee8 environment if it used to run on Jetty 9.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. At the moment, geoserver is installed as a windows service. I will setup an apache environment, put the latest war-file for geoserver inside and point to the data directory.